# ASP.NET Core RC2 crashes on full .NET Framework when using Distributed Caching (SQL Server)

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, dotnet-cli

I have a web project using ASP.NET Core RC2 and dotnet CLI, targeting the .NET Framework, just updated from ASP.NET 5 RC1 and DNX. As soon as I use the distributed SQL Server cache, it crashes with the following exception:

> FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Collections.NonGeneric, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String connectionString)

with the stack trace:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String connectionString)
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous)
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(DbConnectionPoolKey key, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions& userConnectionOptions)
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(DbConnectionPoolKey key)
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value)
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.SqlServer.DatabaseOperations.GetCacheItem(String key, Boolean includeValue)
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.SqlServer.DatabaseOperations.GetCacheItem(String key)
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.SqlServer.SqlServerCache.Get(String key)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.DistributedSession.Load()
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.DistributedSession.Remove(String key)
>   MYCODE.SessionHelper.SetValue(String key, String value) in MYCODE.cs, etc

The line is literally just `Session.Remove(key);`.

I am suspecting that it is trying to load .NET Core packages for some reason instead of realizing that it can use the .NET Framework. Below is my project.json.

```
{
  "webroot": "wwwroot",
  "userSecretsId": "aspnet5-MYCODE-2d5ac1d3-01c8-4be2-9be2-894efd942480",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "gcServer": false,
    "gcConcurrent": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    //"Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms": "1.0.1-rc2-24027",
    //"NETStandard.Library": "1.5.0-rc2-24027",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "MYOTHERCODE": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "System.Text.Encodings.Web": "4.0.0-rc2-24027",
    "Newtonsoft.Json.Schema": "2.0.2",
    "OtpSharp": "1.3.0.4",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.SqlServer": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp": "1.3.0-beta1-20160429-01",
    "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.Common": "1.3.0-beta1-20160429-01",
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "8.0.3",
    "Twilio": "4.7.1"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net46": {
      "imports": [ "dnx451" ],
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.Runtime.Serialization": "4.0.0.0"
      }
    }    
  },

  "runtimes": {
    "win7-x64": {}
  },


  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
    },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    },
    "Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "appsettings.*.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  }
}
```

Adding entries for `Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms` (`1.0.1-rc2-24027`) and/or `NETStandard.Library` (`1.5.0-rc2-24027`) in `dependencies` has not helped. Since the documentation describing how to do this is lacking to nonexistent, I am probably doing something wrong in targeting .NET Framework. The only question is what? Am I missing an import or a reference assembly or something?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly what solved the problem, but removing the `dnx451` import and going down to `net451` worked. This triggered another problem where the class library I use for the database and migrations would be unable to run the `dotnet ef` tool - it [had to be made into an application to be able to do that](http://ef.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cli/dotnet.html#targeting-class-library-projects-is-not-supported) and some mix of configuration changes and simply emptying out the bin and obj folders eventually cleared things up.